# Retrieve all tables selectable by a user (in Oracle)

Tags: oracle, database-permissions

How can I retrieve a list of all tables to which a user is has SELECT permission (either granted directly or through an assigned role)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table_name from TABLE_PRIVILEGES where grantee='USER' and select_priv='Y'
union
select table_name from  user_tables
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks. I didn't know TABLE_PRIVILEGES exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
select owner||'.'||table_name from user_tab_privs where privilege='SELECT'
union 
select rtp.owner||'.'||rtp.table_name from user_role_privs urp, role_tab_privs rtp
  where urp.granted_role = rtp.role and rtp.privilege='SELECT'
union
select user||'.'||table_name from user_tables;
```